# Link to anchor in frame

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

I'm building a portfolio website for a comics label and would like to integrate the store within the site. The site is built in Indexhibit and I've been trying several options.

At the moment I would simply like to be able to have a "BUY IT NOW" link at each product's individual page, and have it open in an anchor or scroll down to it at the store page. The store page is a Tictail shop that opens within the site, in an iframe.

This is the individual page:
http://www.clubedoinferno.com/index.php/project/yonkoma-collection-vol1/

You can see the link code as

```
<a href="http://www.clubedoinferno.com/index.php/store/">BUY NOW</span></a>
```

The anchor at the store for the item was introduced in the item's DIV name, as Tictail enables theme customization:

```
<div id="fH9a">x</div>
```

Using basic stuff like adding #fH9a to my link doesn't work. Help please?

Comment: Of course appending `#fH9a` to the BUY NOW link doesn’t work, because the document that links to is not the document that contains that element – the document _inside the iframe_ is. So you need to include that hash in the URL that you set as the `src` attribute of the iframe.

Comment: Yes, I figured the first part. But how would I do this then? I can't really include the hash in the src url for the iframe as that would entail creating different iframes for each product. I simply want the link to point to that anchor within the iframe.

Comment: _“I simply want the link to point to that anchor within the iframe”_ – that is not directly possible. If you can not output the correct URL for the iframe src directly, then you will have to use a JavaScript that sets it afterwards somehow.

Comment: Any javascript suggestions for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without using a script.

Add the following in [your page in iframe](http://clubedoinferno.tictail.com/)

```
<script>
window.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById(parent.window.location.hash.substring(1)).offsetTop);
</script>
```

The following will give you the anchor part of the url

```
parent.window.location.hash.substring(1)
```

It will be `fH9a` in your case. Then you make the window scroll to the element with that id. It's like

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById("fH9a").offsetTop)
```

Only it's dynamic and will work with any anchor as long as you have the element with the given id in the page.

Pass the id with anchor from [this page](http://www.clubedoinferno.com/index.php/project/yonkoma-collection-vol1/) as follows

```
<a href="http://www.clubedoinferno.com/index.php/store#fH9a">BUY NOW</span></a>
```

Hope that works.

**EDIT**

It appears that the page in `iframe` is not served from the same domain. So the above approach will not work.

But if you update

```
<a href="http://www.clubedoinferno.com/index.php/store#fH9a">BUY NOW</span></a>
```

with

```
<a href="http://www.clubedoinferno.com/index.php/store?fH9a">BUY NOW</span></a>
```

and use

```
document.referrer.substring(1+document.referrer.indexOf("?"))
```

instead of

```
parent.window.location.hash.substring(1)
```

it will (hopefully) work.

Comment: So you say this wouldn't force me to introduce code to the template each time I want to link to that anchor, right? I think Tictail is blocking the code from their end:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://clubedoinferno.tictail.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.clubedoinferno.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Comment: please see the updated answer. that page is not in the same domain, so it wont work (my bad). however it should work with `document.referrer` with some tweaks.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time! It still says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null`

Comment: okay, what do `alert(document.referrer);` and  `alert(document.referrer.substring(1+document.referrer.indexOf("?")));` say?

Comment: It does return a box with `The page at clubedoinferno.tictail.com says: fH9a` or with the page name if I put the first one. Can you remind of the full javascript code? Would I still use getelementbyid?

Comment: okay, that is correct, `fH9a` is the id of the div you wish to focus right? try `alert(document.getElementById("fH9a"));` looks like this is null.

Comment: And do you have <div id="fH9a">x</div> in that page?

Comment: Wait! It's working! I just had to move the code to the end of the page!

Comment: aha! my bad again:] I should have mentioned that:P

Comment: Thank you so so much. I was going crazy just searching the web for something that sounded simple.

Answer (score 1):

Plain HTML

`<a href="https://tictail-shop.fi/#product1" target="shop-frame">Product1</a>`

`<frame src="https://tictail-shop.fi/" name="shop-frame">`

ps. js should follow the html standard in selected implementation in use